make gives gcc: Permission denied - Error 127
I am executing make.
At some point it enters src and from there it tries compiling sources in several subdirectories.
It gives
gcc -x c++ -ggdb -ansi -pedantic -iquote/home/user1/code -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow -fno-common -Dinline=  -Wvariadic-macros  -iprefix /home/user1/code/src/ -iwithprefix . -iwithprefix DataSet -iwithprefix Outputs -iwithprefix Solver -iwithprefix Tools -iwithprefix Models -iwithprefix Modules -iwithprefix Help -iwithprefix Common   -iwithprefix Main -fPIC -fpermissive -c Common/Buffer.c -o Common/Buffer.o
make[1]: gcc: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile:140: Common/Buffer.o] Error 127

But if execute (copy-pasting the echoed command)
$ cd src
$ gcc -x c++ -ggdb -ansi -pedantic -iquote/home/user1/code -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow -fno-common -Dinline=  -Wvariadic-macros  -iprefix /home/user1/code/src/ -iwithprefix . -iwithprefix DataSet -iwithprefix Outputs -iwithprefix Solver -iwithprefix Tools -iwithprefix Models -iwithprefix Modules -iwithprefix Help -iwithprefix Common   -iwithprefix Main -fPIC -fpermissive -c Common/Buffer.c -o Common/Buffer.o

it compiles fine.
What could the cause and solution be?

This is almost certainly an instance of this bug in gnulib (which GNU Make relies on): https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?57962
You don't say what version of GNU Make you're using, but I bet it's GNU Make 4.3.
You can either upgrade your version of GNU Make, or fix your PATH so it doesn't contain any directories which have gcc as a subdirectory, or change your compiler path in your Makefile to be fully-qualified (to avoid PATH search), or add a semicolon to the end of your compile recipe (to force GNU Make to use a shell and not use its "fast path" capability).

You hit the nail in the head, it is gcc 4.3

As per answer by MadScientist, I put together the following script
#!/bin/bash

IFS=':' read -r -a dirs <<< "$PATH"
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "Executing command in $dir"
    find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -name gcc
done

and the culprit directory was revealed.
Then as a quick workaround I did
$ echo $PATH
$ export <output-of-command-above-with-culprit-dir-removed>
$ make

and it worked.
